# Como contar quantas ocorrências de um atributo de uma lista são iguais a um valor? JSF

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Estou precisando contar quantos status são iguais a '1'. Utilizei isso para contar quantos objetos tinha na lista e funcionou. Agora não consigo contar só os que tem status igual a 1.

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:length(cur.listaProdutosManutencao)}" />
```

Esse daí foi o que usei e funcionou.

Tentei este abaixo para pegar o status e não funcionou:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:length(cur.listaProdutosManutencao.status eq '1')}" />
```

Tentei este outro também, e não funcionou:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:join(cur.listaProdutosManutencao.status, '1')}"
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Gostaria de seguir o primeiro que fiz.

Comment: você pode informar mais detalhes? Postá seu beans com isso vc pode criar um método para isso.

Comment: Cara, listaProdutosManutencao é  uma List<ProdutoManutencao> de um objeto com string nome e string status. Apenas isso. Como ficaria?

Comment: Cria um método que que realize isso para você. Onde você verificaria  o status dentro de um for ficarias mais fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Coso, você esteja usando JDK 8 pode usar  lista.forEach(action). Eu varia um método para isso.

```
public Integer totalStatus ( List<ProdutoManutencao> lista, String status){
      Integer  result = 0;
      //validacao para a  lista null ou status.
     for (ProdutoManutencao object : lista) {
         result += object.stattus.equals(status) ? 1 : 0;   
      }
     return result;
  } 
}
```

No seu .xhtml você pode chamar o seu método. Poder ser um método mais curto que ja faca isso direto no seu Bean sem  precisar passar parâmetros.

```
<h:outputText value="#{cur.totalStatu( cur.listaProdutosManutencao() ,"1") }" />
```